# No output through fields_for when using a one to one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, one-to-one, has-one, fields-for

I've been having some trouble trying to get *fields_for* to produce an output when trying to display my User and Profile model on a single form, these use a *has_one* and *belongs_to* relationship.

So here are extracts form the top of the model classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

The controller is pretty simple and standard:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

And here is a snippet out of the view as it currently stands:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <% f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= profile_form.label :name %><br />
      <%= profile_form.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've tried other things, like this:

```
 <% fields_for @user.profile do |profile_form| %>
```

And everything works fine if I manually add the field:

```
  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_name">Name</label><br>
    <input id="user_name" name="user[profile_attributes][name]" size="30" type="text" value="<%= @user.profile.name %>">
  </div>
```

It's worth mentioning that I'm fairly new to rails and not exactly sure how these functions work under the hood although I've read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) and [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). Also in my searches a lot of the examples of fields_for a one to many relationship so perhaps I'm going about this in the wrong way?

All help, advice and further reading is much appreciated :-)

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
<% f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
```

Doesn't that need to be written like this (due to Rails 3 new behavior):

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
```

Comment: I knew that it would be something simple - thanks a lot :-)
I've only started rails from version 3, it can be difficult when searching to look at the differences between the versions although something like this can be easily skipped. Anything worth reading in relation to this?

Comment: Not really. Helpers were a pain to write in Rails 2 (albeit more memory-efficient) if they used an ERB block (`do %> ... <% end`). In Rails 3 they decided to just make everything work like a simple string. Thus, if you forget to add `=` the string is not printed. But many examples from Rails 2 times won't have that `=` - a caveat.

Comment: I've been struggling getting this to work for 2 hours now. You totally saved my bacon with this one - just wish I'd Googled it sooner! Thanks so much!